# java - odbc - insert into syntax error

Tags: java

I am trying to update a access database via odbc driver through java.

Table name is form1

I am getting a syntax error when I execute this command:

```
updates="INSERT INTO form1 
(entrydate,name,gender,month,date,phno,emailid,facebookid,address,semester,
bloodgroup,slno,college,department,liveprojects,trainings); 

values("+abc+",'"+t3.getText()+"','"+t4.getText()+"',"+def+","+def1+","+zzz+",'"
      +t8.getText()+"','"+t9.getText()+"','"+t10.getText()+"',"+aaaa+",'"
      +t12.getText()+"',"+xyz+",'"+t13.getText()+"','"+dd+"','sa','da')";
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's that `;` doing after the column list? (And please do read about sql injection and bind parameters.)

Comment: You shouldn't be using ODBC, use a real JDBC driver instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your statement - a real and a potential one:

- Real: the semicolon before the `values` keyword needs to be removed
- Potential: the statement needs to be converted for use with parameters, otherwise a single quote in the body of any of the string parameters will cause a syntax error.

Here is how you can switch to parameterized prepared statements:

```
String updates="INSERT INTO form1 (entrydate,name,gender,month,date,phno,emailid,facebookid,address,semester,bloodgroup,slno,college,department,liveprojects,trainings) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement psUpd = con.prepareStatement(updates);
psUpd.setInt(1, abc);
psUpd.setString(2, t3.getText());
psUpd.setString(3, t4.getText());
psUpd.setInt(4, def);
psUpd.setInt(5, def1); // The types of parameters need to match the type of setXYZ
... // Continue for the remaining parameters, then call
psUpd.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

First problem:

```
updates="INSERT INTO form1 
(entrydate,name,gender,month,date,phno,emailid,facebookid,address,semester,
bloodgroup,slno,college,department,liveprojects,trainings);
```

**you are separating field and values with ;  but it will be  blank **

Secondly It is best to use prepareStatement

```
String sql ="INSERT INTO TableName  
(entrydate,name,gender,month,date,phno,emailid,facebookid,address,semester,
bloodgroup,slno,college,department,liveprojects,trainings) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?); 

    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql );    
     int index = 1;
    ps.setInt(index++, abc);
    ps.setString(index++, t3.getText());
    ps.setString(index++, t4.getText());
    ps.setInt(index++, def);
    ps.setInt(index++, def1); // The types of parameters need to match the type of setXYZ
    ... // Continue for the remaining parameters, then call
    ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: when PreparedStatement used i get message Driver does not support this function....why do i get this message????i use access 2003 and Odbc Driver

Comment: I used the following code and it worked..Thanks guys for the help....cheers                                                            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
 String insert="insert into Students (slno,entrydate,names,gender,dob,phno,emailid,facebookid,address,semester,bloodgroup,college,department,liveprojects,trainings) " +
             "values("+serialno+","+entdate+",'"+nameofs+"','"+Gender+"',"+bod+","+phone+",'"+emaid+"','"+femaid+"','"+addr+"',"+sem+",'"+bg+"','"+coll+"','"+depto+"','java','java')";

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `;` before `values`.

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

Use `INSERT INTO form1 values(value1,value2......);` **directly.**

**2.** If you want to stick to your own format... then **do the following changes.**

**-** Remove the `;` **before the** `values.`

**-** To insert the **comma**, its **better to use** `","` **instead of** `','`

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon (;) after the column names is the culprit. You are terminating the statement by doing that. 
just remove the ; . your code will work.

Comment: Also make use of prepare statements. Its not good to inject directly the values in the string.

Answer (score 0):

try this.....

```
updates="INSERT INTO form1(entrydate,name,gender,month,date,phno,emailid,facebookid,address,semester,bloodgroup,slno,college,department,liveprojects,trainings) 
values( '"+abc+"','"+t3.getText()+"','"+t4.getText()+"','"+def+"','"+def1+"','"+zzz+"','" +t8.getText()+"','"+t9.getText()+"','"+t10.getText()+"','"+aaaa+"','"
  +t12.getText()+"','"+xyz+"','"+t13.getText()+"','"+dd+"','sa','da')";
```